# How to download multiple images in single XML call?

Tags: image, download

I'm working on an iPhone app, in which I need to download 100-200 images from server using image url in a for loop. Like following :

```
 NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
        NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                selector:@selector(downloadImages:)
                                                                                  object:arrayTemp];
        [queue addOperation:operation];
        [operation release];
        [queue release];

-(void)downloadImages{

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
UIImage *image;
for (int i=0; i < [self.ImagesRecords count]; i++)
{
    ImageData *data =(ImageData*) [self.ImagesRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%@",data.ID];
    image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://abc.com" stringByAppendingString:data.PhotoPath]]]];
    if (image!=nil)
    {
        [self saveImage:image withName:strName];
    }
}
image = nil;
[pool release];
}
```

Its working fine and giving me image as well.

My questions are :

1. How can I get multiple images data in a single XML call? Is it possible?
2. What's the batter way to download images? Please provide piece of code.
3. Some times I found that my app gets stuck for a while, when this image downloading is in progress. What's the reason of it?

Answer (score 0):

1. multiple images example in 1 xml:

```xml
<xml>
    <info>
        <width>55</width>
        <height>41</height>
    </info>
    <image_data>
        <data>
            <name>Background</name>
            <data>data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...</data>
        </data>
        <data>
            <name>Layer #2</name>
            <data>data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...</data>
        </data>
        <data>
            <name>Layer #3</name>
            <data>data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...</data>
        </data>
    </image_data>
</xml>
```

Comment: You can post XML fine - it needs to be inside code markup, which is a bit odd when nested inside a list.